# Run a Discord Bot on Replit

Tags: discord.py, replit

I tried to run a simple discord bot on replit to make him online forever
I followed so many tutorials and installed all the libraries but i got this error on replit, and i couldn't fix it [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BG83Q.png)

Can someone please help me to fix it ?

or suggest another way to make discord's bot alive

trying to make a discord bot alive

Comment: Don't (ab)use replit's service to run a discord bot, it'll cause you dozens of issues. Just get a VPS. Also, YouTube tutorials are really bad for more reasons than I can fit in this comment, but most importantly they teach you terrible practices & you don't learn anything. Just read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not using the correct `discord.py` library (could be from a different library that has the same import name) because your code looks good

Try `pip uninstall discord.py` and `pip install discord.py`